# Issues with importing python 3 libraries in Sublime Text 3

Tags: environment-variables, sublimetext3, python-3.6, path-variables, sublime-build

I'm on a Mac and I've recently added a python3 (3.6) build for Sublime 3, and it seems to work. However, when I import libraries installed with pip3, I get this strange output in the Sublime IDE.

For example, I tried importing Numpy (my script did nothing else) and I get this output:

```
sh: sysctl: command not found  
sh: grep: command not found  
sh: sw_vers: command not found  
sh: grep: command not found
```

If I import multiple libraries, I get this output repeated once for every library that I try to import.

There is another thread here on the forum which suggests adding my path variable to the existing $PATH. I tried this and it did not work. I'm not so experienced dealing with path variables, so I'm guessing that I just failed at doing it right.

How do I solve this issue?
Thank you!

P.S. Here's the build:

```
"path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/:$PATH",
"cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
```

edit: added the build

Comment: Can you also include the build system that you're using for this?

Comment: Yes, good point! added now.